# Registration form not submitting and drop down box not populating

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a registration form for my website.

One of the fields on my registration form is a drop down box that is populated by a table on my MySQL database.

I originally wrote the registration script a different way but I needed to change how the form worked to accommodate the new drop down box and the way it gathered its data.

Before the changes the form was successfully submitted, but now it just gives me a white screen.

I have checked the mysqli_connect.php with an if-else statement. It showed that it was working but no registrations were being sent to the MySQL server when the submit button was pressed. Also, the drop down box was not showing any of the content from the MySQL table that it was linked to.

Below is a copy of the script that I am using:

```
<?php
@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
echo "<h1>Register</h1>";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  $errors = array();
  if (empty($_POST['firstname'])){
    $errors[] = 'Your forgot to enter your first name.';
  }else{
    $firstname = trim($_POST['firstname']);
  }
  if (empty($_POST['lastname'])){
    $errors[] = 'Your forgot to enter your last name.';
  }else{
    $lastname = trim($_POST['lastname']);
  }
  if (empty($_POST['username'])){
    $errors[] = 'Your forgot to enter your  username.';
  }else{
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
  }
  if (!empty($_POST['password1'])) {
    if ($_POST['password1'] != $_POST ['password2']) {
      $errors[] = 'Your password did not match the confirmed password!';
    }else{
      $password = trim($_POST['password1']);
    }
  } else {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your password!';
  }
  if (empty($_POST['birthdate'])){
    $errors[] = 'Your forgot to enter your  birthdate.';
  }else{
    $birthdate = trim($_POST['birthdate']);
  }
  if (empty($_POST['gamespyid'])){
    $errors[] = 'Your forgot to enter your  gamespy id.';
  }else{
    $gamespyid = trim($_POST['gamespyid']);
  }
  if (empty($errors)) {
    require ('mysqli_connect.php');
    $q="INSERT INTO Users (firstname, lastname, username, password1, birthdate, gamespyid, base) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', SHA1('$password1'), '$birthdate', '$gamespyid', '$base')";
    $r = @mysql_query($dbc, $q);
    if ($r){
      echo'<p>You are now registered</p>';
    }else{
      echo'<p>You have not been registered</p>';
    }
  } else {
    echo 'Error<br> <p>The following errors have occured:<br/>';
    foreach ($error as $msg) {
      echo " - $msg<br/>\n";
    }
    echo '</p><p>Please try again.</p><p><br/></p>';
  }   //if no errors
}     //submit
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="../pages/register.inc.php" method='POST'>
    <table summary="REgform">
      <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td>

        <td><input type='text' name='firstname' value='<?php echo $firstname; ?>'></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Last Name:</td>

        <td><input type='text' name='lastname'value='<?php echo $lastname; ?>'></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>

        <td><input type='text' name='username'value='<?php echo $username; ?>'></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>

        <td><input type='password' name='password1'></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Repeat Password:</td>

        <td><input type='password' name='password2'></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Birthdate:</td>

        <td><input type='text  ' name='birthdate'value='<?php echo $birthdate; ?>'></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Gamespy Id:</td>

        <td><input type='text' name='gamespyid'value='<?php echo $gamespyid; ?>'></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Base:</td>

       <td><select name="base" size="1">
          <option>
            Select One
          </option>
         <?php  require('http://www.virtual-aviation.org/gatewayaviation/admin/mysqli_connect.php');
         $q = "SELECT  id, CONCAT_WS(' ', airport_name, airport_code) FROM airports ORDER BY airport_code ASC";
         $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
         if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($r, MYSQL_NUM)) {
         echo "<option value=\"$row[0]\"";
         if (isset($_POST['existing']) && ($_POST['existing'] == $row[0]) ) echo 'selected="selected"'; echo ">$row[1]</option>\n";
         }
   } else {
   echo '<option>Please a new airport first.</optioon>';
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
         ?>
        </select></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'></p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Errors found in the dropdown box area
**Warning**:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in **/home5/virtua15/public_html/gatewayaviation/pages/register.inc.php** on line **178**

**Warning**:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in **/home5/virtua15/public_html/gatewayaviation/pages/register.inc.php** on line **180**
Please a new airport first.

Comment: You can use require function only to include files in `relative to the current directory` and not like what you did

Comment: You can also simplify the first condition from `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){` to `if(!empty($_POST)){` and test with `var_export($_POST)` :)

Comment: try to print the query and check the drop down value was passed.

Comment: @F.Orvalho if my issue were resloved I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't require from 'http'. You need to change

```
require('http://www.virtual-aviation.org/gatewayaviation/admin/mysqli_connect.php');
```

to some local path like

```
require('mysqli_connect.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO First check your mysql query by echoing it and then run the query through editor.

Second, although you have set display_errors but still you might not able to view the errors.